# Letterspacing in GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, fonts

[image: Emacs letterspacing]

I'm using GNU Emacs on 64bit Ubuntu. Monaco font works well, except the gap between each letter is too wide, thus causing each line of codes to spread too widely. I thought maybe it was a problem with the font, but then Ubuntu terminal was capable of handling the exactly same font with a narrower horizontal margin.

Is there any method I can try to adjust the horizontal linespacing in Emacs?

Comment: I don't think you will find and answer to this short of changing the font or the variant. Emacs' font rendering (although improving) is still far behind many of the other GUI programs that are around. You'd best use a font that looks nice by default rather than Monaco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked that Emacs and terminal really display the font differently? In your screenshot, the font size itself in Emacs is bigger.

Anyways, you can choose different spacing values when setting a font by appending them to the font name, e.g.  `"Monaco-10:spacing=110"`. Try if you can get the behaviour you want this way.

EDIT: Maybe the second paragraph of my answer should be disregarded. I basically guessed this based on the output of `describe-font`, but further experiments with it didn't yield satisfying results.

Comment: actually i think the fonts are the same size. Due to the wide spacing, the font in Emacs looks bigger than the terminal's font.

Comment: I have now checked with Monaco myself, and the thing seems to be that Monaco-9 and Monaco-10 both actually use the same glyphs, only Monaco-9 has bigger spacing both horizontally and vertically. As far as I can see, you should get the same font as in your terminal by setting Emacs' font to Monaco-9.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

M-x customize-face

At the prompt enter "default"

I adjust the font-width from medium to condensed and see if that helps.

Otherwise you might just try a different font.  SHIFT + Mouse-1 should bring up a menu where you can change the default font from Courier.

Answer (score 1):

I suffer the same problem, but then I googled into this post: 
http://www.gringod.com/2006/11/01/new-version-of-monaco-font/

it definitely solves my issue.

The fix is rather simple, download the linux version of Monaco font and everything would be fine. :)